# Butter Knife lib issue

Tags: java, android, butterknife

If have bind the view onCreate View but `onclick` is not working.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);
    unbinder= ButterKnife.bind(getActivity(),myview);
    return myview;
}

@OnClick(R.id.bnRetrofit)
public void retrofitTest() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hello from Butterknife OnClick annotation",`Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

What is the solution?

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
unbinder= ButterKnife.bind(getActivity(),myview);
```

to

```
unbinder= ButterKnife.bind(this, myview);
```

The first parameter of `bind()` is the "target" object which contains the annotated class members which are to be bound.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use proper syntax. Use following:

```
ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
```